# Как обучить модель по своей функции sklearn?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, sklearn, linear-gradient

У меня имеется 150 значений функции, при том, что ее параметр х увеличивается на 1 с каждым разом. Мне требуется вывести 150 следующих значений, при увеличении х на 1. В функции есть так же 2 неизвестных массива, которые как раз нужно найти, что бы вычислить след значения. Подскажите , как это делать, в туториалах только примеры со всякими табличками, где много данных, у меня же есть только результат функции и сама функция с двумя неизвестными

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, существует бесконечное множество решений такой задачи, если не накладывать никаких дополнительных ограничений на эти ваши неизвестные два массива. Единственный разумный вариант тут - это вообще забыть про два неизвестных массива и просто рассматривать значения функции как временной ряд. Для прогнозирования временного ряда существует множество способов, но тут нужен предварительный анализ данных - посмотреть распределение, есть ли в данных какая-то повторяемость и т.д.

А может наоборот у вас данные настолько линейные, что их обычная линейная регрессия от ряда значений `x` может предсказать. Но не видя данные ничего конкретного сказать нельзя.

Comment: функция выглядит так- 0+∑(4)⋅cos((/+/24)⋅2). Известен t, он увеличивается на 1